# simpledialog.askstring window from tkinter freezes

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

I have a problem using simpledialog.askstring from tkinter, it opens two pop up windows, one of them is the regular one to input a value, but the other is a blank window that freezes completely and you have to force the cloosure of the window, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVH3u.jpg)as shown in the image in the link. I'm using spyder.

What could be happening?

This is what I have so far:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QComboBox, 
QLabel, QPushButton, QGroupBox
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
from PIL import ImageGrab
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
# import imageToString
import pyperclip
import webbrowser
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 
r"C:\Users\amc\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

class Communicate(QObject):

snip_saved = pyqtSignal()

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
    self.win_width = 340
    self.win_height = 200
    self.setGeometry(50, 50, self.win_width, self.win_height)
    self.setWindowTitle("PSD Generator")
    self.initUI()
    
def initUI(self):

    #Define buttons
    self.searchOpen = QPushButton(self)
    self.searchOpen.setText("Digitilize Graph")
    self.searchOpen.move(10,75)
    self.searchOpen.setFixedSize(150,40)
    self.searchOpen.clicked.connect(self.snip_graph_clicked) 
    
    self.copyPartNum = QPushButton(self)
    self.copyPartNum.setText("Snip Table")
    self.copyPartNum.move((self.win_width/2)+10, 75)
    self.copyPartNum.setFixedSize(150,40)
    self.copyPartNum.clicked.connect(self.snip_table_clicked) 

    self.notificationBox = QGroupBox("Notification Box", self)
    self.notificationBox.move(10,135)
    self.notificationBox.setFixedSize(self.win_width-20,55)
    
    self.notificationText = QLabel(self)
    self.notificationText.move(20, 145)
    self.reset_notif_text()
    
    
def snip_graph_clicked(self):
    
    self.snipWin = SnipWidget(False, True, self)
    self.snipWin.notification_signal.connect(self.reset_notif_text)
    self.snipWin.show()
    self.notificationText.setText("Snipping... Press ESC to quit snipping")
    self.update_notif()

def snip_table_clicked(self):
            
    self.snipWin = SnipWidget(True, False, self)
    self.snipWin.notification_signal.connect(self.reset_notif_text)
    self.snipWin.show()
    self.notificationText.setText("Snipping... Press ESC to quit snipping")
    self.update_notif()
    
    
def reset_notif_text(self):
    self.notificationText.setText("Idle...")
    self.update_notif()
    
def define_notif_text(self, msg):
    print('notification was sent')
    self.notificationText.setText('notification was sent')
    self.update_notif()

def update_notif(self):
    self.notificationText.move(20, 155)
    self.notificationText.adjustSize()
    

class SnipWidget(QMainWindow):

notification_signal = pyqtSignal()

def __init__(self, copy_table, scan_graph, parent):
    super(SnipWidget, self).__init__()
    self.copy_table = copy_table
    self.scan_graph = scan_graph
    root = tk.Tk()# instantiates window
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    self.setGeometry(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height)
    self.setWindowTitle(' ')
    self.begin = QtCore.QPoint()
    self.end = QtCore.QPoint()
    self.setWindowOpacity(0.3)
    self.is_snipping = False
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(
        QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
    )
    self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    self.c = Communicate()
    
    self.show()
    
    if self.copy_table == True:

        # the input dialog
        BH_Ref = simpledialog.askstring(title="New PSD",prompt="Borehole Number Ref:")
        Depth = simpledialog.askstring(title="New PSD",prompt="Sample depth (m):")
        self.c.snip_saved.connect(self.searchAndOpen)
        
    if self.scan_graph == True:
        # the input dialog
        BH_Ref = simpledialog.askstring(title="New PSD",prompt="Borehole Number Ref:")
        Depth = simpledialog.askstring(title="New PSD",prompt="Sample depth (m):")
        
        self.c.snip_saved.connect(self.IdAndCopy)
        
        
def paintEvent(self, event):
    if self.is_snipping:
        brush_color = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        lw = 0
        opacity = 0
    else:
        brush_color = (128, 128, 255, 128)
        lw = 3
        opacity = 0.3

    self.setWindowOpacity(opacity)
    qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    qp.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor('black'), lw))
    qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(*brush_color))
    qp.drawRect(QtCore.QRect(self.begin, self.end))

def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
        print('Quit')
        QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor();
        self.notification_signal.emit()
        self.close()
    event.accept()

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.begin = event.pos()
    self.end = self.begin
    self.update()

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    self.end = event.pos()
    self.update()

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    x1 = min(self.begin.x(), self.end.x())
    y1 = min(self.begin.y(), self.end.y())
    x2 = max(self.begin.x(), self.end.x())
    y2 = max(self.begin.y(), self.end.y())
    self.is_snipping = True        
    self.repaint()
    QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    self.is_snipping = False
    self.repaint()
    QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
    img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    self.snipped_image = img
    QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor();
    self.c.snip_saved.emit()
    self.close()
    self.msg = 'snip complete'
    self.notification_signal.emit()
    
    
def searchAndOpen(self):
    img_str = self.imgToStr(self.snipped_image)
    msg_str = f'Text in snip is {img_str}'
    
    
def IdAndCopy(self):
   img_str = self.imgToStr(self.snipped_image)
   pyperclip.copy(img_str)
   
def find_str(self, image_data):
    
    img = image_data

    h,w = np.shape(img)
    asp_ratio = float(w/h)
    img_width = 500
    img_height = int(round(img_width/asp_ratio))
    desired_image_size = (img_width,img_height)
    img_resized = cv2.resize(img, desired_image_size)
    imgstr = str(pytesseract.image_to_string(img_resized))
    print(imgstr)
    return imgstr
    

def imgToStr(self, image):
    # img_str = imageToString.main(image)
    img_str = self.find_str(image)
    return img_str


def window():
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

win = MyWindow()
win.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

Comment: There can be various reasons. We need your code to tell the one that applies to your case.

Comment: Thanks @Thingamabobs for the swift response. I added the code to the main post, if you could check it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: It seems you are using PyQt5 mainly. Why do you mix it with tkinter ? Didnt you know about `PyQt5.QInputDialog`? It is generally a bad idea to mix GUI frameworks together except for those that are whitelisted from the frameworks themselves.

Comment: I suggest you read how to create a [example]. The code in this question contains a whole lot of extra stuff that might not be needed to demonstrate your problem. And, in removing the extra stuff and creating the example, you might figure out the problem yourself.